# Enterprise database design

Tags: database-design

we have customer who want to make some product  [like this](https://go.tradegecko.com/#/account/users) or more specifically she needs replica of this product which is a generic inventory,product,customer etc management system. And the reqirement document she sends contains just  module names like

```
1. Inventory Management
2.  Order Management
3.  Vendor Management
4.  Customer Management
5.  Front E-Commerce Store
6.  Online Purchase Orders
7.  Payment Integrations
8.  Products Management
9.  Shipping Management
```

Being a database designer how to model these things as i don't have any clear requirements document.
From where should i start to go into he right direction.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Ask the client? I mean...how exactly do you expect us to guess the client's requirements any better than you?!

Comment: Requirement is to make replica of above mentioned system.

Comment: If you don't know what she wants, and she doesn't know what she wants, then I'd recommend you both save time and money and just buy her a license for TradeGecko. Because no one here can help you...

Comment: what will you do if you have been asked to make replica of some application at very high cost?

Comment: I'd ask the client for an actual list of requirements...

Comment: and if client ask you to gather requirements by yourself and give you this kind of reference site?

Comment: Open the site, make notes of what you need based on what they capture and come back for us to critique when you've made an effort to do something yourself.

Comment: Well i am following this book http://www.amazon.com/Data-Model-Resource-Book-Vol/dp/0471380237. Is it good approach?

Comment: That book may help *once you have requirements*, but you must have a better set of requirements before you can even start. Your client needs some proper business analysis work done to establish what they need the resulting system to achieve (outputs, user stories and processes, inputs). Don't try do this BA work for them (certainly not for free) - it can be very time consuming and is going to need some experience if the client *really* doesn't currently know what they want in any detail other then "something like this <points>".

Comment: @DavidSpillett well i am not doing it for free but i will have to do this BA part as well.That's why asking for an expert opinion  to actually find a direction. from where should i start if i have no prior experience of modeling these kind of databases.

Comment: The point is that you should not even be thinking about modelling until you know some detail about *what* you are modelling. The desired inputs and outputs (and there scale) could dictate overall structure (even general technology used) considerably. The BA work would preferably come first, not be done in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your link prompts me to create an account. Anyhow, she wants a system which handles her universal business processes. Looking at the modules she wants, these are very generic modules, so a lot of options can be used. Unless there are no very specific needs - business processes and business rules that deviates from the universal business processes, or a specific database structure due to the exchange with more other database systems - I don't recommend you to reinvent the wheel. In case you still wonder how you could create your own universal model, or just grab information out of it, [Data Model Patterns by David C Hay](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780133492125/samplepages/0133492125.pdf) is a great informative book.

My personal choice would be to do a good research in business-to-business application solutions or other open source universal database models, I'm sure there are plenty to find, then alter the database on eventual specific needs of your client.